# how to skip specific element of xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have below xslt. which is used to normalize the whole xml.

normalize_xslt = '''

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>'''
```

it able to normalize xml properly, But say I have an XML like below:

xml = \

```
    """
    <rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns:junos="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/17.4D0/junos" xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="urn:uuid:5c4d99db-5b2b-4c88-8f69-8fe1d2c29bfe">
<output>
 CPU       Name      Time(ms)
 85%       Idle      4801438332
 13%    Threads      782332270
  0%        ISR      10860088
  0%    Level 1      10854137
  0%    Level 2      5949

Last Long Running Thread Event time 200 ms

 CPU       Name      Time(ms)    Count

 Top Thread:
   pid      = 99
   name     = LU Background Service
   time     = 266630752 ms
   cpu      = 4%

</output>
</rpc-reply>
"""
```

I want to skip such xml where xml element is `<output>`
What need to be changed in my xslt?

Answer (score 1):

Add a template that copies the element through

```
<xsl:template match="df:output" xmlns:df="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

. If you want to "normalize" the name and remove namespaces then use

```
<xsl:template match="df:output" xmlns:df="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

If the namespace can change but the root element local name `rpc-reply` and the `output` name are known to indicate you don't want to change anything then you could also add e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/*[local-name() = 'rpc-reply' and *[local-name() = 'output']]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

which would copy then any such document without applying the other templates.

Comment: with this its removing whole output. I am just getting `<rpc-reply>urn:uuid:5c4d99db-5b2b-4c88-8f69-8fe1d2c29bfe</rpc-reply>`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you want to achieve. What do you mean with `skip specific element`? Consider to edit your question and to show the result you want.

Comment: I don't want to apply normalize-space if the XML tag is `<output>` as I have one in my posted xml.

Comment: Is that for any `output` element at any position/level in the XML input? And do you want to have that XSLT return nothing or the original XML if there is an `output` element present?

Comment: I want the original XML to be returned. `output` element will be root only

Comment: In your posted sample the `output` element is not the root element, the root element is `rpc-reply`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. It will alway be `<rpc-reply<output>string blob which should not be normalized</output></rpc-reply>` . Your example is working, but do I need to keep namespace definition. As for different XML namespace can change

Comment: I have added a third variant which copies the document node if there is a root element of name `rpc-reply` with a child `output` in any namespace.

Comment: Looks like some issue with syntax as I getting lxml.etree.XSLTParseError: Cannot parse stylesheet. I corrected the type loal-name, still the same issue.

Comment: This seems to be working fine.     `<xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='rpc-reply']/*[local-name()='output']">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>`

Comment: I have corrected the two problems in the last template of the answer.